# Saving drawings into phone gallery-returns null all the time

Tags: android, image

I'm following a tutorial online on how to create a simple drawing application. Everything works fine except for the part in the code where you save the image you just created. For some reason, the image name is always null even when I hardcode it. As a result, I can't save the image into the phone gallery.

```
   else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //save drawing
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                //attempt to save
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
                //feedback
                if(imgSaved!=null){
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    unsavedToast.show();
                }
                drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.show();
    }
```

[image not being saved to phone gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJcar.jpg)

Comment: I think it's better etiquette to provide your source code as formatted text instead of as an image. We could also use a screenshot of the results (where the name is null).

Comment: are you sure that it should be saved as a `".png"`?

Comment: Does that make a difference?